# Is it there any good package for Emacs to do bug/issue tracking locally?

Tags: problem-tracking

Does anyone know any good Emacs package or solution for local bug/issue tracking?

Comment: "Locally" as in single-user? Org-mode should be more than sufficient, I would think? "Locally" as in anything else? You might like to mention some actual requirements.

Comment: The only thing I know are the packages flycheck.el or flyspell.el. They perform a syntax checking while writing.

Comment: I am not looking for syntax checking, I am looking for bug/issue tracking system. Something such as Mantis bug tracker or github issue tracking. But can run locally (security policy) and well integrated with Emacs is the best.

Comment: @phis. Yes, `locally` means single use and just run on my computer. Org-mode is good and very powerful. But I hope to have some extension packages that I don't have to manually code everything, such as, create project, maintain issue id, add timestamp, etc.

Comment: I don't use Jira but I have heard of it. Here's an emacs package for Jira: https://github.com/baohaojun/org-jira

Comment: There's this project https://github.com/aki2o/emacs-bts (which I didn't try), and there's also some Emacs mode which manages Emacs' own bugs. I can swear I saw it, and even was considering repurposing it for my own project, but now I've completely forgotten the name and was hoping someone else would remember it.

Comment: Ah, found it: `M-x debbugs-gnu-bugs`.

Comment: You may find what you're looking for by searching for "offline bug tracker" or "distributed bug tracker".  There's a good [StackExchange question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186628/textbased-issue-tracker-todo-list-for-git) discussing different packages; perhaps one of them will fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

When I was in a team which every colleague is an Emacs user, I just put a `TODO.org` in our git repository and put all issues we found in the file.  This worked amazingly well for the project.

No wait for remote access, no browser to launch, no hassle to edit in a browser's text box and no excuse to read facebook posts ;-p.   And it gave us the full power of Org, sorting, searching, tagging, easy markups, you name it.  We comfortably stayed in our Emacs session for good.

When we were done with an issue, pushed it and took another issue.  You could change `TODO` to `DOING`, or whatever your team agrees on, and commited it again.

For us, and it was a small, 5 max, and local team, we didn't bother doing `TODO` -> `DOING` commit.  Even with people remotely working, I'd say you could use IRC or some other communication tools to sync what you are working on.

I wish all editor gets the first class Org support so that I can use this method all the time.

Try it and tell me your experience!

Comment: And now there's https://github.com/danielma/magit-org-todos.el to make TODO.org + magit work better :)